# I have to write some code but I’m completely stuck, any help would be amazing

Tags: r

I have to create a code or function in R that displays all the even numbers from 6:500 and beside each one any 2 prime numbers which can be added together to get said even number. I am really struggling with this and so far all I have got is a vector of the even numbers and a vector of the prime numbers. I have some idea of what I have to do but I have not clue how to code it! Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/4996248). As it is, this question lacks adequate focus.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I'm sure there's a more efficient way to do it, but you're probably going to want to nest a loop inside a loop.  I'm going to use the library `primes` to generate my prime numbers because I'm lazy and it has a built in variable `primes` that contains the first 1000 primes.

```
library(primes)
#generate the even numbers from 6 to 500
evens <- 3:250 * 2

#generate the prime numbers less than 500
p <- primes[primes < 500]
```

But you said you already had that, but now I'm going to start making a data frame because I think better in data frames:

```
#The name of variables 'n' and 'x' are arbitrary
df <- data.frame("n" = evens,"x" = 0)
```

The `0` in column `x` is just a placeholder that I plan to fill in with my loop.

```
#add the library tidyverse because it contains the %in% notation that you'll want
library(tidyverse)

#start the loop and have it run from the first row to the last
for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {

  #make a temp value n that will be used in the next loop
  n <- df$n[i]

  #start a second loop that runs through each p such that p < n
  for(j in p[p < n]) {

  #Take the j's and subtract them from n.
  #If they are in p, then we have 2 primes that add to the right number
    if((n - j) %in% p) {

      #If we found one prime, them we assign it to that placeholder in x and break the loop
      df$x[i] <- j
      break
    }
  }
}

#Now that we're done, we can just add a new column that is the difference of the previous two.
df$y <- df$n - df$x
```

Comment: Hey thanks so much for helping me out! I was trying this out in r and it keeps saying it can’t find the function %n% even tho I’ve installed the tidy verse package

Comment: I think that should be `%in%`, and it's part of the `tidyverse` library

Comment: Sorry I miss read that in the code, got it to work now, thank you very much! I really appreciate it!